# Ubuntu 18.04 - "All shell packages missing" after botched file copy

Tags: command-line, gnome, package-management

I changed the background image of the Gnome sign-in screen a while ago.  When the package gets updated, my changes get wiped, so after reinstating the change, I copied the new ubuntu.css file to ubuntu.css.bak.  I wanted to make sure that this remained in place, so I put a line in /etc/rc.local to copy ubuntu.css.bak to ubuntu.css.

However, I fat-fingered it and typed:
cp /usr/share/gnome-shell.theme/ubuntu.css.bak /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
Note the "." in the source-file path instead of "/"

Now, when I boot up, X doesn't come up.  If I log in via the command line after ctl-alt-F2, then type "startx", I get: "All shell packages missing" and I get a blank black screen - no icons, no dock, nothing.

Got in via ssh from another machine and did the copy correctly, but still no joy.  Also tried "export DISPLAY=:0" first, but that didn't help.

Any ideas?  Basically, I'm running CLI Linux again.  Shades of Slackware, circa 1994.  Help!

Thanks in advance!